# Cant authenticate my ACS token

Tags: android, rest, azure, acs, azureservicebus

Ive been trying to send messages to a azure service bus queue from android for a while and i just cant get it to work. This is the code i use for getting the ACS SWT:

```
    private void getTokenFromACS() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://servicebusnamespace-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/");
        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wrap_name", "name"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wrap_password", "password associated with the name"));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wrap_scope", "Realm url"));


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse)httpclient.execute(httppost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

        String[] tokenVariables = URLDecoder.decode(reader.readLine()).split("&wrap_access_token_expires_in=");


        authorizationToken = tokenVariables[0];

    }
```

This works fine, i get a string that has the wrap_access_token, issuer, audience, expiresOn and HMACSHA256.

What i try to do after that is to send a message with this token like this:

```
    HttpClient requestClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://servicebusnamespace.servicebus.windows.net/queuename/messages");
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "WRAP access_token=\""+authorizationToken+"\"");

        Item item = new Item();
        Date date = new Date();
        item.setDate(date);
        item.setId(1);
        item.setRoadName("roadname");
        item.setSpeed(60.0);
        item.setLat(12.12);
        item.setLng(12.12);

        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(item, Item.class);
        post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.getBytes("UTF8")));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = requestClient.execute(post);
```

This always result in my Token not being authenticated, i get the error message saying my token doesnt containt a signature or that it doesnt have the audience set. What could be wrong?

Note that this is on android =)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody has an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing some code. Your **authorizationToken** is currently something like this: "wrap_access_token=net.windows.servicebus.action%3dLis..."

The only thing you want is the part after the **equal-sign**.

I think this will do:

```
String[] tokenVariables = URLDecoder.decode(reader.readLine()).split("&wrap_access_token_expires_in=")[0].split("=");
authorizationToken = tokenVariables[1];
```